# Text in second column not starting where it should

Tags: two-column

[image: The problem]

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}[12pt]
\usepackage{nth}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in}


\makeatletter
\let\origsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar{\starsection}{\nostarsection}}

\newcommand\nostarsection[1]
{\sectionprelude\origsection{#1}\sectionpostlude}

\newcommand\starsection[1]
{\sectionprelude\origsection*{#1}\sectionpostlude}

\newcommand\sectionprelude{%
  \vspace{1em}
}

\newcommand\sectionpostlude{%
  \vspace{1em}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\Huge
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{CURRICULUM VITAE}
\Large
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa} 
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\nth{1} dadad, dadwraf,
afafaf} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\large
\begin{resume}

\Large
\section{University:} \large
B.Sc of Pure Mathematics \\
University of something

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you turned your code into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Where do you want the text to go? You just mention that it doesn't start where it should.

Comment: Exactly in front of each section, as opposed to one line below.

Comment: Please add some explaining text _in your question_. For your screenshot the left side is not needed at all. In fact, the picture is absolutely not helpful in the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to the font sizes specified by the class, but if you must use `\Large` and `\large` for your regular document content, you'll have to do some legwork:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}% http://ctan.org/pkg/res
\usepackage{nth,changepage}
\newcommand{\Lstrut}{{\Large\strut}}
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection{\Large#1:}\Lstrut\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{adjustwidth}{-\hoffset}{0pt}
\begin{center}
  \Huge CURRICULUM VITAE

  \bigskip

  \Large aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

  \nth{1} dadad, dadwraf, afafaf
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{resume}
\large
\section{University}
B.Sc of Pure Mathematics \\
University of something
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Also consider the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) class for setting a curriculum vitae.

Comment: @Galactus: If this answer solved your problem, consider [accepting it](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ) as such.